# JQuery tabs() method issue, tab creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out an error with JQuery when I tried to create tabs for my ASP.Net application(I am a novice in JQuery)..

Below is the code I am trying, when I tried debugging using Chorme Dev.tool found error"no such method 'add' for tabs widget instance" and I found out "tabsDiv.tabs("add", '#main', pages[i][0]);" this does not work anymore as the "add" method is deprecated from the newer version of JQuery.
Could anyone help me to find way to overcome this??

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var pages = [
            ['Events', "/Listings.aspx", "/AddEvent.aspx", "UpdateOrDelete.aspx"],
            ['Performance', "/Performance.aspx"]
        ];

        var myPage = '<%=Request.Path %>';

        var tabsDiv = $('#masterTabsDiv');

    tabsDiv.tabs({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            document.location = pages[ui.index][1];
            return false;
        }
    });
    var indexToSelect = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < pages[i].length; j++) {
            if (pages[i][j] == myPage) {
                indexToSelect = i;
                window.alert("set block 2");
                break;
            }
        }
        tabsDiv.tabs("add", '#main', pages[i][0]);
    }
    window.alert("set block 4");
    tabsDiv.find('li').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active');
    tabsDiv.find('li').eq(indexToSelect).addClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active');
});
</script>
```

Thanks,
Raam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since jQuery UI 1.10 you need to add a new `li` element to the DOM and then call `.tabs("refresh")`, so your code will be something like

```
var tabsDiv = ('#masterTabsDiv');
tabsDiv.find('ul').append("<li><a href='#newTab'>New Tab</a></li>");
tabsDiv.append("<div id='newTab'>New content</div>");
tabsDiv.tabs("refresh");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got it.. I am just wondering what does        this function do? I know it is adding tabs but what does the document.location = pages[ui.index][1]; mean??? Sorry I am a novice to JQuery.. tabsDiv.tabs({
            select: function (event, ui) {
                document.location = pages[ui.index][1];
                window.alert(document.location);
                return false;
            }

Comment: `document.location` has been deprecated for a long time, you should use `window.location` instead. It looks like what it's doing is manually triggering the tab to open by redirecting the browser when the tab is clicked - but I'm not too sure. I don't think you need it though, can you try with just `.tabs()` and see if it stops working?

Comment: Thank you, another clarification on this, I have this array of pages             var pages = [
                ['Events', "/Listings.aspx", "/AddEvent.aspx", "UpdateOrDelete.aspx"],
                ['Performance', "/Performance.aspx"]
            ]; How do I add this to <li> manually??